# Using QueryRescorer to Re-score Documents

Tags: java, lucene

Lucene implemented a new class called QueryRescorer which supposedly is useful if you want to implement a more resource intensive sorting operation on the top N Lucene search results.

Unfortunately, I don't actually understand how the class is to be used. Here is the documentation page:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/QueryRescorer.html

The primary method appears to be:

```
public static TopDocs rescore(IndexSearcher searcher,
          TopDocs topDocs,
          Query query,
          double weight,
          int topN)
```

For example, what is this 'query' that is passed in? The original query? Or is it a kind of secondary query that is used in the re-ranking?

If anyone actually understands how this works, I'd be very appreciative of an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a different query.  The idea of the `QueryRescorer` is that your first pass would use a broadly defined query, which would perform well, but not completely express what you need to search for.  Then the second pass, you use a more precise, but more expensive, query.

For an example, take these documents:

> 1 - "relevant test text"
>   2 - "superrelevant test text"
>   3 - "ultramightyrelevant test text"
>   4 - "uninteresting test text"
>   5 - "And lots more documents that have nothing to do with this query..."

I want to search for documents documents containing "relevant" and "test text", but I want to be tolerant of hyperbole when searching for "relevant".  I could just query for `*relevant* "test text"`, but I know that leading wildcard is going to absolutely murder search performance.  Instead, I can first query with `"test text"`, which will get all four of those documents, and then pass `*relevant*` to the QueryRescorer, to boost the scores of the documents I *really* want.

```
Query prequery = parser.parse("\"test text\"");
Query postquery = parser.parse("*relevant*");
TopDocs docs = searcher.search(prequery, 10);
docs = QueryRescorer.rescore(searcher, docs, postquery, 2, 10);
```

Comment: Cool, that makes sense now. Thanks!